# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup_graph'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and trying to implement code written here 
http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-i.html.

I am trying to implement same code but I am getting error

> no module name basic_rnn

while importing `basic_rnn` as written in the code:

```
import basic_rnn
def plot_learning_curve(num_steps, state_size=4, epochs=1):
    global losses, total_loss, final_state, train_step, x, y, init_state
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    losses, total_loss, final_state, train_step, x, y, init_state = \
    basic_rnn.setup_graph(g,basic_rnn.RNN_config(num_steps=num_steps, state_size=state_size))
    res = train_network(epochs, num_steps, state_size=state_size, verbose=False)
    plt.plot(res)
```

then I changed `basic_rnn = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell`, 
then I am getting error

> 'module' object has no attribute 'setup_graph'.

I am assuming I will again get error in while implementing `basic_rnn.RNN_config`.
What would be the correct syntax?
I am using tensorflow of version 1.0.0
pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the gist code provided by the author, r2rt:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5fc9903990ecec5f09361934920bb999. Though you need to tweak the code a bit to get it run.

Basically, you need to implement the setuo_graph and RNN_config functions in basic_rnn.py. But since there are three versions of RNNs that the original blog is comparing, I think it would be better if you put RNN_config in one Python file.

Besides, I found some of r2rt's code is deprecated, so I adapted the code and created my own repo. Check it out if you are interested:
https://github.com/innerfirexy/rnn-tf-r2rt

You can run the code in run_RNNs.py in IPython. I changed the gist code a bit by moving the RNN_config function to train.py, and giving train_network a config parameter.